# Why I am getting this errors?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to access to a method named `sendHttpPost(final AsyncReponseHttpSending delegate, final String urlString, final Object data)`, which is in another class, and this class has a private constructor. However when I get the method like `HttpSending postMethod = HttpSending.sendHttpPost()` and I start to pass the same parameters than in the original class I get the error "delegate is always null" , "data is always null", delegate is an instance of the `AsyncResponseHttpSending` interface which have only one method `void onHttpResult(int httpCode, String httpMessage, String body);`what am I doing wrong?

Class from where I get the method

```
public class HttpSending {
    private static final String TAG = "HttpSending: ";

    private static final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = (int) (30 * UnitsConstants.SECOND_TO_MILISECOND);
    private static final int TIMEOUT_READ = (int) (60 * UnitsConstants.SECOND_TO_MILISECOND);

    private HttpSending() {

    }

    public static void sendHttpPost(final AsyncReponseHttpSending delegate, final String urlString, final Object data) {
        new Thread(TAG) {
            @Override
            public void run() {

      //BUNCH OF CODE

               }
        }.start();
    }
```

Class where I do my request

```
public class HttpPost {

    AsyncReponseHttpSending delegate = new AsyncReponseHttpSending() {

        @Override
        public void onHttpResult(int httpCode, String httpMessage, String body) {

        }
    };

    final String url = "https://postman-echo.com/post";
    final Object data = null;

    HttpSending postMethod = HttpSending.sendHttpPost(delegate,url,data );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
HttpSending postMethod = HttpSending.sendHttpPost(delegate,url,data );
```

should not compile because `HttpSending.sendHttpPost` is a `void` method.

Comment: what should I do then, make it return something?

Comment: If it needs to return something, then yes.  If it doesn't need to, then change the line with the error so that it *doesn't* assign the non-existent result.  Only >>you<< know if it needs to return something .... and why.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @Stephen C, could you please tell me why it has to return something? it would be really helpful for me, thank u a lot once again

Comment: I never said that it needs to return something. What I said was that you yourself need to work out if that method needs to return something, or if it doesn't need to return something. This is your code. The code's design is in >>your<< mind ... not in mine.  (Then having worked out what the code needs to do, you make sure that the method signature and the method body and the method call(s) are mutually compatible.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you never instantiate `delegate` that's why you get the warnings for its null.

Comment: yes I did, I forgot to paste the code :( still nothing, just updated it